# Pushing UIViewController leads to shine through effect when transitioning

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

I've got a `UIViewController` as the rootViewController of a `UINavigationController`. This viewController has got a `UITableView` as a subview. If I push another viewController in the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method of the `UITableViewDelegate` (which is the viewController) the old view is shining through the navigationBar and tabBar of the newly pushed view. If the push transition is complete, the effect is gone.

Before that I used a `UITableViewController` which didn't show this effect. But I had to move to a `UIViewController`and an embedded `UITableView` because I wanted to have a `UIToolBar` below the navigationBar.

Thanks for your help!